select first option of dropdown on change event in angular
<select [(ngModel)]="profile.type" name="type"(change)="selectPhoneType($event,mailCreate,'phone4_Value')">
                        <option value="">Select type</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let types of mobiletypes" [ngValue]="types.value">
                          {{types.value}}
                        </option>
                        <option value="addMore">Add More</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>

i have this dropdown when i change the dropdown value it should automatically select the
 selectPhoneType(event,mailCreate,type)
  {
    this.activeType=type;
    event.preventDefault();
    let value = event.target.value;
    if(value=='addMore')
      {
        this.addMailCreateLabel(mailCreate);
        this.profile.type='';
      }
  }

first value but in my case it is not selecting first value after addMore is selected.

It's due to timing issue, from the value being set to AddMore, to being set again to empty string. We can solve it with the below code:
...
if (value == 'addMore') {
      // this.addMailCreateLabel(mailCreate);
      // will execute after the synchronous tasks are done, after which the select picks up the update!
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.profile.type = null;
      });
}
...

Full code:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="profile.type" name="type" (change)="selectPhoneType($event,mailCreate,'phone4_Value')">
      <option [value]="null">Select type</option>
      <option *ngFor="let types of mobiletypes" [value]="types.value">
        {{types.value}}
      </option>
      <option [value]="'addMore'">Add More</option>
    </select>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  mobiletypes = [{ value: 'test' }];
  profile: any = {
    type: null,
  };
  mailCreate = 'Y';
  activeType = '';
  selectPhoneType(event: any, mailCreate: any, type: any) {
    this.activeType = type;
    event.preventDefault();
    let value = event.target.value;
    if (value == 'addMore') {
      // this.addMailCreateLabel(mailCreate);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.profile.type = null;
      });
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
